# Options value data-bind not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having an issue in mapping the elements of an object and binding them to an `<option>` element using Knockout.js.

The relevant section of HTML is as follows:

```
<!-- ko if: parentObjectExists -->
<!-- ko with: parentObject -->
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="subTaskDistributionInput">Distribution:</label>
 <select id="subTaskDistributionInput" data-bind="options: options.distributions,  optionsText: 'value', value: key" class="form-control input-sm"></select> 
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

The elements of the options.distributions array contain two elements, `key` and `value`. Relevant Javascript:

```
function Options(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.distributions = ko.observableArray(data.Distributions);

  //Disposal
  self.isDisposed = false;
  self.dispose = function () {
      self.distributions.dispose();
      self.isDisposed = true;
  };
}
```

And the output options tags:

```
<option value>Average</option>
<option value>Triangular</option>
```

A Distribution contains two elements: `key`, an integer, and `value`, a String. 
The `value` element is definitely coming through accurately into `optionsText`, but the `key` attribute is not coming through into the HTML at all. I'm almost certain the issue here lies in the HTML. Alternative `value:` bindings that I've tried are `'key'`, `function() { return key; }`, `$data.key` and `item.key`, but none of these have worked. If anyone can see what I'm missing here, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you print the `options` observable result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should write

```
optionsValue: 'key'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it like this

```
<select id="subTaskDistributionInput" 
    data-bind="
        options: distributions,
        optionsText: $root.getValue,
        optionsValue: $root.getKey
    " 
class="form-control input-sm"></select>
```

Also see `optionsValue` instead of `value`

#### Fiddle Demo

See the [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)

Comment: This is a great answer, and I appreciate the work you put into it. I've only selected the other answer as it was the simplest modification that produced the desired result. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. When you have complex objects and want to extract ids and values from an object this will work fine